# Dynamically allocated two-dimensional array access issue C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am having an issue with accessing 2d array elements.
While creating an object I allocate memory for my array in the constructor.

Once the object is created when I try to access array elements I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

I checked and when still in constructor I can access array elements.
I don’t know what I am doing wrong.

This is my class where I allocate memory for data array;

```
class TableData
{
public:
    TableData(std::string name, int rows, int columns) : tableName(name), rowCount(rows), columnCount(columns)
    {
        data = new std::string*[rowCount]; 
        for (int count = 0; count < rowCount; ++count)
            data[count] = new std::string[columnCount];
        columnID.resize(columnCount);

        //Below I did a test where can see that I can access array elements
        data[0][0]=“test1111”;
        std::string test = data[0][0];
    }
    ~TableData()
    {
        for (int count = 0; count < rowCount; ++count)
            delete[] data[count];
        delete[] data;
    }
    std::string **data;
    std::string tableName = "";
    const int rowCount;
    const int columnCount;
    std::vector<std::string> columnID;
};
```

When I try to fill an array with data I am getting "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)"

```
ecuData.tables.push_back(TableData(name, tableRowCount, tableColumnCount));
ecuData.tables[i].data[0][0]=“test2222”; // Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
```

“tables” is a vector of TableData objects

Here is a full function:

```
void Decoder::getTables(std::fstream &fs, std::vector<char> & buffer, SGBDdata &ecuData)
{
    const int ptr_offset = 0x84;
    int tableOffset = *reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(&buffer[0] + ptr_offset);
    const int tableCountBufferLength = 4;
    vector<char> tableCountBuffer;
    
    fs.seekg(tableOffset, fs.beg);
    readAndDecryptBytes(fs, tableCountBuffer, tableCountBufferLength);
    
    int tableCount = *reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(&tableCountBuffer[0] + 0);

    for(int i = 0; i < tableCount; ++i) //iterate through tables
    {
        int tableBufferLength = 0x50;
        vector<char> tableBuffer;
        readAndDecryptBytes(fs, tableBuffer, tableBufferLength);
        string name(tableBuffer.begin(), tableBuffer.begin() + 0x40);
        TrimEnd(name);
        
        int tableColumnOffset = *reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(&tableBuffer[0] + 0x40);
        int tableColumnCount = *reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(&tableBuffer[0] + 0x48);
        int tableRowCount = *reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(&tableBuffer[0] + 0x4C);
        

        //**This is where I am creating new “TableData” object and putting it into vector<TableData>**
        ecuData.tables.push_back(TableData(name, tableRowCount, tableColumnCount));

        
        long savedPos = fs.tellg();
        fs.seekg(tableColumnOffset, fs.beg);

        //Load column names
        for(int j = 0; j < tableColumnCount; ++j)
        {
            int tableItemBufferLength = 1024;
            vector<char> tableItemBuffer;

            for(int k = 0; k < tableItemBufferLength; ++k)
            {
                readAndDecryptBytes(fs, tableItemBuffer, 1);
                if (tableItemBuffer[k] == 0)
                    break;
            }
            ecuData.tables[i].columnID.push_back(string(tableItemBuffer.begin(), tableItemBuffer.end() - 1));
        }
        
        for(int j = 0; j < tableRowCount; ++j)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < tableColumnCount; ++k)
            {
                int tableItemBufferLength = 1024;
                vector<char> tableItemBuffer;

                for (int l = 0; l < tableItemBufferLength; ++l)
                {
                    readAndDecryptBytes(fs, tableItemBuffer, 1);
                    if (tableItemBuffer[l] == 0)
                        break;
                }
            
                string s(tableItemBuffer.begin(), tableItemBuffer.end() - 1);
                ecuData.tables[i].data[j][k] = s; //**This is where I get my fault**
            }
        }
        fs.seekg(savedPos, fs.beg);
    }
}
```

Here is SGBDdata class. The ecuData object of this class contains a vector data

```
class SGBDdata
{
public:
    std::string sgbdPath;
    std::string ecuName;
    std::vector<JobData> jobs;
    std::vector<TableData> tables;
};
```

Comment: Read up on how to provide a [mcve].  The problem is likely to be in code you haven't shown and, since you haven't provided a [mcve] the only way anyone can help you is to guess about what code that you haven't shown is actually doing.

Comment: Wild guess: push_back is making a copy, using the default copy constructor, which does a shallow copy, which immediately turns to mush when the temporary is destroyed. Either define a proper copy constructor or use emplace instead of push_back.

Comment: Can you post more code where you get the error? We don't know what parameters you're passing. So, as @Peter mentioned, give a proper example.

Comment: @dratenik, I have tried emplace_back instead of push_back. Unfortunately it didn't work. As you mentioned it must be something with the way the object gets inserted into vector.

Comment: The default shallow copy contructor is openly dangerous for your class, [prohibit its use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/explicitly-defaulted-and-deleted-functions?view=msvc-160). This will also give you an error wherever you are unknowingly using it.

Answer (score 0):

lose all the new, delete, and pointer magic. and use a vector of vectors?

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
class TableData
{
public:
    TableData(std::string name, int rows, int columns) : tableName(name), rowCount(rows), columnCount(columns)
    {
        data.resize(columnCount);
        for( int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
        {
            data[i].resize(rowCount);
        }
        columnID.resize(columnCount);

        //Below I did a test where can see that I can access array elements
        data[0][0]="test1111";
        std::string test = data[0][0];
    }
    ~TableData()
    {
       
    }
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> data;
    std::string tableName = "";
    const int rowCount;
    const int columnCount;
    std::vector<std::string> columnID;
};

int main()
{
  TableData test = TableData( "me", 3,3);
  test.data[0][0]="test2222";
  std::cout<<test.data[0][0];
}
```

Comment: that solution is indeed simpler and most likely I will end up with using it however I would really like to know how to get it working with old fashion arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the code working. As @dratenik mentioned the problem was related to shallow copy which was taking place in default copy constructor. To get it fixed I have added a move constructor to TableData class.

```
class TableData
{
public:
    
    TableData(std::string name, int rows, int columns) : tableName(name), rowCount(rows), columnCount(columns)
    {
        data = new std::string*[rowCount];
        for (int count = 0; count < rowCount; ++count)
            data[count] = new std::string[columnCount];
        columnID.resize(columnCount);
    }
    TableData(TableData&& t) : rowCount(t.rowCount), columnCount(t.columnCount)
    {
        tableName=t.tableName;
        data = new std::string*[rowCount];
        for (int count = 0; count < rowCount; ++count)
            data[count] = new std::string[columnCount];
        
        for (int r_count = 0; r_count < rowCount; ++r_count)
            for (int c_count = 0; c_count < columnCount; ++c_count)
                data[r_count][c_count] = t.data[r_count][c_count];
    }
    ~TableData()
    {
        for (int count = 0; count < rowCount; ++count)
            delete[] data[count];
        delete[] data;
    }
    std::string **data;
    std::string tableName = "";
    const int rowCount;
    const int columnCount;
    std::vector<std::string> columnID;
};
```